# Color .xyz files with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, colormap

I like to know how can I color a xyz file based on the Z values(elevation) with QGIS, by python or graphicly

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].